# How to vertically and horizontally centre this input field in its container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontally and vertically centre this input field inside its container ( the green box )

Is there a way to do it without CSS3 flexbox techniques ?

Everything i've tried including normal centering techniques, margin and auto, and positioning doesn't work.

Well, the problem with positioning is that it does work, but there has to be a better way that moving it down.

Any ideas?

Here is the page: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/new.html

I am trying to centre the input with an id #searchInput

Comment: you can put it in a table and use `vertical-align` on the td element

Comment: well, I guess vertical-align is supposed to work with inline elements, not just td, but that's the only time I've been able to successfully render them.

Comment: Ah, I try to not use tables. But thank you.

Comment: No prob, it's personal preference, but imho, I find them very structurally sound. In most cases, people defend their avoidance of tables because it is not as 'clean', however, I've found that their alternatives become muddier than if they had just constructed a simple table. Sry to rant, lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the section container, then use absolute positioning to vertically centre align the input field using a negative margin of half the input height:

```
#input {
    position: relative;
}

#searchInput {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.809rem;
}
```

Comment: @Connor I didn't know about this unit of positioning until today, but since they are using rem as the unit of measurement for the input field it seemed appropriate

Comment: see http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem for more info on rem

Comment: @Connor i love using rem. To me, it is the best of px and the best of em.

Comment: Thanks, i knew `REM` exists but i also thought that it is highly depreciated

Comment: @Connor what? As far as I know, it is pretty new and part of css3

Comment: @Irfan Mir maybe its something else i'm thinking of then

Comment: @Connor possibly. It doesn't make sense to be that something modern browsers are supporting is going to be deprecated. http://caniuse.com/#search=rem

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div style="display:table;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">centered box</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V8GUn/

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your code

```
#searchInput { margin-top: 5px; }
```